# How to get the flattened ( 7* 7* 512 = 25088) values of the last convolution block (7,7,512) of VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Currently I am using VGG-16 to extract features of an image dataset. I trained it on a certain type of data set and what I would like to do is the following to get the last convolution block weights as a flatten format in order to create a 25088-D feature vector.
My model summary is the following :

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
vgg16 (Functional)           (None, 7, 7, 512)         14714688  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 10)                40970     
=================================================================
Total params: 134,301,514
Trainable params: 134,301,514
```

what i tried to do so far is the following :

```
all_weights = []
for layer in model.layers:
  print(layer.name)
  w = layer.get_weights()
  all_weights.append(w)
```

to get all the layers weights and then to access the last block of the second layer (vgg16)
what i got from the `len(all_weights[2])` is a 26 lists and the last list is made of 512 values (most probably the bias terms). Does anyone knows how to get this (7,7,512) weights out of these lists ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hello @Holt, sorry I didn't understand the relation between the number of channels and the weights because I  think the shape will be adjusted during the multiplication of the image area with their corresponding filters

Comment: If you have 512 kernels of shape 7x7 you don't have a weight matrix of shape 7x7x512, you have a weight matrix of shape 7x7xNx512 (or whatever is the order in tensorflow) .where N is the number of input channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is

```
model.get_layer("vgg16").weights[-2]
```

As you noticed the `-1` index gives you the bias, and `-2` will give you the weight.

Note that this is **not** a tensor of shape (7, 7, 512). (7, 7, 512) is the output shape of the VGG16 block, the weight matrix shape is (KH, KW, Cin, 512) where (KH, KW) are the height and width of the kernel and Cin the number of input channels. If you use the standard VGG16 from `tf.keras.applications`, then the shape will be (3, 3, 512, 512).

Comment: Thank you very much @Holt for the clear explanation! Do you know any possible methods to get a feature vector out of the trained model ? Because i want to use this feature vector to do clustering later on

Comment: @Markh You can always create a model using `tf.keras.models.Model(model.inputs, model.get_layer("vgg16").outputs)` and then use it to extract features. If the `vgg16` inside your model is already another model, you can probably do it without having to construct a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with model.layers[1].weights?

Comment: Hey, @Angel Luis first thank you for your response!
yes i have tried to use ```model.layers[1].weights``` it gives me the entire topology's weights and not the weights after the 2D-MaxPooling in the vgg architecture, i will try to do manually the 2D-MaxPooling if it's the only way to do it..